# Pausing a process for a pre-set (hardcoded) period of time

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I am fooling around with NSTimer in a program I am writing and am having some troubles envisioning how I can do a specific task.  What I want to have happen is that I want the process I am running (a method responding to a button push) to pause for a period of time and then continue.  I can get the basic timer stuff to work by creating the timer in the button push method then watching it fire off and invoking a second method.  However, I am not sure how I would go about pausing the button push process that spawned the timer in the first place.

Is there a way to have the button push method wait around until the timer methods fires off and tells the button push method to 'go'?   Is there a queue type entry or notification type entry that I can wait on in the button push method that would be sent by the timer selector method?

Any info would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to pause the main thread where your logic is running.  Try using

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 1.0]; //pauses the thread for one second
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I kept looking at the NSTimer methods and while they looked very useful and were easy to use, I just kept scratching my head...